# Implementing snapConfiguration to SliverPersistentHeader

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I am trying to implement snap feature to SliverPersistentHeader but couldn't figure it out and couldn't find a good documentation on this.

My code:

```
    class MyDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate  {
      double he;
    
      MyDelegate ({required this.he}) : super();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
        return AnimatedContainer(
          child: const Text('Title', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
          color: Colors.green,
          height: he,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        );
      }
    
      @override
      double get maxExtent => kToolbarHeight;
    
      @override
      double get minExtent => 0;
    
      @override
      bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return true;
      }
    
      @override
      FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration get snapConfiguration => FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration();    
    }
```

Floating is set to true.

I am getting error message for vsync being null.
I couldn't make it work. I need help on implementing snap feature for SliverPersistenHeader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Only thing I needed to do was providing vsync.
For that I need to add `with TickerProviderStateMixin` to my code:

```
class _CustomBodyState extends State<CustomBody> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

and in the build method `vsync: this`:

```
child: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(delegate: MyDelegate(minExtent: 0, maxExtent: kToolbarHeight, vsync: this), floating: true),
          const CustomSliverListTile(),
        ],
      ),
```

and changed the MyDelegate as:

```
class MyDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate  {
  @override
  final double minExtent;
  @override
  final double maxExtent;
  @override
  final TickerProvider vsync;

  MyDelegate ({required this.minExtent, required this.maxExtent, required this.vsync}) : super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      child: const Text('Title', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
      color: Colors.green,
      height: maxExtent,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

@override 
  FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration get snapConfiguration => FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration(
    curve: Curves.linear, 
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
  );
}
```