# How to add snap to `SliverPersistentHeader` between expanded and collapsed states?

Tags: flutter

My goal is to implement a snap behavior for a `SliverPersistentHeader` that doesn't allow the header to "stop" the animation in the middle, but snap to the begin or the end based on the offset of the view, just like `PageController` does.

I tried the solution proposed [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370253/implementing-snapconfiguration-to-sliverpersistentheader) but it didn't work

Here's the code that I currently have that I'm trying to implement this snapping behavior:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverPersistentHeader(
            pinned: true,
            delegate: CustomAppBarDelegate(
              minExtent: kToolbarHeight,
              maxExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
              vsync: this,
              expandedWidget: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Center(child: Text('Header expanded'))),
              collapsedAppBar:
                  Container(height: kToolbarHeight, color: Colors.blue, child: Center(child: Text('Header collapsed'))),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  const CustomAppBarDelegate({
    required this.minExtent,
    required this.maxExtent,
    required this.vsync,
    required this.expandedWidget,
    required this.collapsedAppBar,
    this.leading,
    this.trailing,
    this.backgroundColor,
  });

  @override
  final double minExtent;

  @override
  final double maxExtent;

  @override
  final TickerProvider vsync;

  final Widget expandedWidget;

  final Widget collapsedAppBar;

  final Widget? leading;

  /// Leading widget for the app bar. If null, no trailing widget will be shown.
  final Widget? trailing;

  final Color? backgroundColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final formattedMaxExtent = maxExtent - kToolbarHeight - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    var expandedOpacity = 1 - (max(0, shrinkOffset) / formattedMaxExtent);
    expandedOpacity = max(expandedOpacity, 0);
    expandedOpacity = min(expandedOpacity, 1);

    final collapsedOpacity = shrinkOffset > formattedMaxExtent ? 1 : max(0, shrinkOffset) / formattedMaxExtent;

    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(child: Opacity(opacity: expandedOpacity, child: Material(child: expandedWidget))),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: collapsedOpacity.toDouble(),
            child: ColoredBox(color: backgroundColor ?? Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: collapsedOpacity.toDouble(),
            child: AppBar(
              systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
              ),
              shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              titleSpacing: 0,
              title: collapsedAppBar,
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        if (leading != null)
          Positioned(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 12, left: 16, child: Material(child: leading)),
        if (trailing != null)
          Positioned(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 12, right: 16, child: Material(child: trailing))
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration get snapConfiguration => FloatingHeaderSnapConfiguration(
        curve: Curves.linear,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      );
}
```

Comment: "[...] just like PageController does" - so you need a custom `ScrollPhysics` similar to [PageScrollPhysics](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/796c8ef792/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart#L532)

Comment: That's correct. I used https://pub.dev/packages/snap_scroll_physics as a reference to create my own scrolling behavior. Could you write the suggestion as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: write a self answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom scroll solution as suggested by @pskink using https://github.com/jamesblasco/snap_scroll_physics as a reference, although this library itself would solve the issue.